# Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' when changing wallpaper from Launcher

Tags: android, exception, filenotfoundexception, user-permissions

I noticed that Google has introduced a new external storage permission model in KitKat, and I suspect the error I'm getting has to do with it. As a snippet of my code,

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Uri uri) {
        Intent result = new Intent();

        if (getActivity().getIntent().getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false)) {
            result.setClipData(new ClipData(documentItem.getSimpleName(), new String[]{"*/*"}, new ClipData.Item(uri)));
            result.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        } else {
            result.setData(uri);
            result.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
        }

        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
```

Essentially, this piece of code is called to change the wallpaper from Launcher Activity, either Action Launcher or Google Now launcher.

Note that I've also added the permission in AndroidManifest, which apparently isn't necessary, and shouldn't be the cause of the problem.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I'm getting the following error,

```
12-17 12:19:16.085 19459 20444 W BitmapCropTask: cannot read file: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/android_app/cache/skydroid_file_cache/89399873/IMG_6586.JPG
12-17 12:19:16.085 19459 20444 W BitmapCropTask: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/android_app/cache/skydroid_file_cache/89399873/IMG_6586.JPG: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
12-17 12:19:16.085 19459 20444 W BitmapCropTask:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
```

Also, I've tried to monitor the external storage and I see files being downloaded with a file name that looks something like _false.0, which I'm unable to open.

If you've ever experienced the same issue, please give a helping hand!

Comment: @saganaut But notice that it attempted to open the file and raised EACCES (Permission denied). And I'm pretty sure the file exists because that's the same directory I wrote to on external storage. Thanks!

Comment: @saganaut Yes, even if that's the case, it shouldn't raise that error correct? I used a third party file explorer and checked if the directory is being created, and it is.. So I' not sure..